# Add Constraints in a Conditional Query/Operation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements, average, threshold

I use the following function to perform a conditional operation on a List:

```
consider[data_, conditionCOL_, conditionVAL_, listOfCol_] :=
  Select[data, (#[[conditionCOL]] == conditionVAL) &][[All, listOfCol]]
```

Considering the following example :

```
dalist = Join[Tuples[Range[4], 2]\[Transpose], {Range[16], Range[17, 32, 1]}
         ]\[Transpose];
```

[image]

I use the following to obtain the means of specific columns defined by the function.
This will output the means of entries of column 3 & 4 for which the corresponding entry in column 1 equals 2

```
Mean@consider[dalist, 1, 2, {3, 4}]
```

[image]

Now, I would like to add constraints/thresholds on the values to be averaged :

***Average the values when they are:***

- Above minValue (e.g., 3)
- Under maxValue (e.g., 25)

Below, an example is given of values the average value of which should be calculated under the above mentioned constraints.

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, in your initial code, the `Select` statement, alone, returns exactly what your looking for, as `MapThread[{#1, #2}&, ...]` and `Transpose` are exact inverses of each other.

Comment: @rcollyer, Thank You, I adapted it from the follwing, and supressing the #3 I did not think about redundency !
                                                                     
MapThread[Disk[{#1, #2}, #3] &, 
 Transpose@
  Partition[
   Flatten@Union[
     Select[t4dataLAEH10, (#[[9]] == disp) &][[All, 54 ;; 77]]], 3]]

Comment: suppose you only wanted the first 4 points, i.e. `{conditionCOL, conditionVAL}={1,1}`. What filtered average would you expect from that? There are two ways to interpret it: both columns must meet the filter criteria, which gives an avg of `{4,20}`, or each column is filtered independently which gives an avg of `{4, 37/2}`. The current answers give the former result, while I suspect you wish the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is not clear whether you want just to exclude the points outside of the limits from the averaging, or to decide whether or not to perform the averaging, I will address both questions. You can use the following functions to postprocess the results of your `consider` function (they are rather specific, based on your data format):

```
filter[data : {{_, _} ..}, {min_, max_}] := 
   Select[data, min < #[[1]] < max && min < #[[2]] < max &]

dataWithinLimitsQ[data : {{_, _} ..}, {min_, max_}] := 
   data == filter[data, {min, max}]

meanFiltered[data : {{_, _} ..}, {min_, max_}] := 
   Mean@filter[data, {min, max}]
```

Here is how you can use them:

```
In[365]:= dalist=Join[Tuples[Range[4],2]\[Transpose],{Range[16],Range[17,32,1]}]\[Transpose]
Out[365]= {{1,1,1,17},{1,2,2,18},{1,3,3,19},{1,4,4,20},{2,1,5,21},{2,2,6,22},{2,3,7,23},
{2,4,8,24},{3,1,9,25},{3,2,10,26},{3,3,11,27},{3,4,12,28},{4,1,13,29},{4,2,14,30},{4,3,15,31},
{4,4,16,32}}

In[378]:= considered = consider[dalist,1,1,{3,4}]

Out[378]= {{1,17},{2,18},{3,19},{4,20}}

In[379]:= filter[considered,{2,21}]

Out[379]= {{3,19},{4,20}}

In[380]:= dataWithinLimitsQ[considered,{2,21}]

Out[380]= False

In[381]:= meanFiltered[considered,{2,21}]

Out[381]= {7/2,39/2}
```

Comment: @rcollyer  Hope we'll get even some day :) Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: Thank You Leonid, once again. I leave unanswered a little to see if others feel inspired, but this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Cases`:

```
inRange[data_, {min_, max_}] := Cases[data, {__?(min < # < max &)}, 1]
```

This form also accepts data with an arbitrary number of columns.

```
dat = {{1, 2, 0}, {6, 7, 4}, {6, 7, 7}, {4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 3}, {9, 7, 1}, {0, 3, 7}, {6, 2, 1}}

inRange[dat, {2, 7}]

(* Out = {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 3}} *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the first two columns of the OP's data are filtered by that pattern and it doesn't directly allow different filter ranges for the last two columns. As an alternate pattern, I'd use `{_, _, _?(min1 < # < max1&), _?(min2 < # < max2&)}`.

Comment: @rcollyer my expectation was to use `inRange` _after_ `consider`.  Are you suggesting a solution that combines these functions?  Also, did 500 ask for a different range for each column?

Comment: there is some ambiguity as to what he actually wanted, as of yet he hasn't responded to my comment, above. My nit was referring to this ambiguity, and was not intended to suggest combining the two operations. Incidentally, Leonid's answer behaves the same way. Also, no he did not ask for a different range for each column, I was just being presumptuous/proactive.